# Google fonts not working on any browsers or tablets

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-api, google-webfonts

I am having a serious issue with Google fonts. They were working fine till last week and since then they have stopped working on all the browsers and tablets. If I manually install fonts on my PC then only they show up but not very accurately.

Header code of API:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

CSS:

```
body { font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #4c4c4c; background: url('images/textures/header_bg1.png') no-repeat center top, url(images/textures/11.png) 0px 0px; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 6px; color: #474747; line-height: 1em; font-weight: 300; }
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: #2b2b2b; }
h1 { font-size: 41px; font-weight: 300; color: #5a5a5a; margin-top: 25px;  margin-bottom:5px;}
h2 { font-size: 30px; font-weight: 300; margin-top: 25px;  margin-bottom:5px;}
h3 { font-size: 23px; font-weight: 300; margin-top: 25px;  margin-bottom:5px;}
h4 { font-size: 18px; font-weight: lighter; margin-top: 25px;  margin-bottom:5px;}
h5 { font-size: 16px; font-weight: lighter; margin-top: 25px;  margin-bottom:5px;}
h6 { font-size: 14px; font-weight: lighter; margin-top: 25px;  margin-bottom:5px;}

p { font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #4c4c4c; text-align: justify; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 25px;}
```

Link to the site that I'm working on: http://www.bpcdev.co.uk

Comment: No problems here: http://jsfiddle.net/PXvv3/

Comment: Hi Juhana, thanks for your help. Yeah you're right the fonts are showing up on jsfiddle. Here's the site that I'm working on and all it shows is Arial and ignore google api. http://www.bpcdev.co.uk

Comment: The font seems to be loading fine. Where is the style sheet where you are assigning the font to the document body (or specific classes, etc.)?

Comment: Hi Pekka, Thanks for your reply.. I have added the stylesheet code above where it is being used on the css i.e. h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
padding-bottom: 6px; color: #474747; line-height: 1em; font-weight: 300; } If i change from 'Tahoma' to 'Times New Roman' it then applies the Times New Roman style but ignores the Google font.

Comment: Did a bit of reverse engineering by taking everything off from the header file javascripts/jquery/external css and just left the Google API font links and also deactivated all the plugins being used in wordpress. Yet the fonts are still not showing up. :(

Comment: http://www.bpcdev.co.uk/ shows with Open Sans.

Comment: You should set up a minimal demo page that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thanks Jukka and sorry about the mess right now.. on mine only Times New Roman shows up :s. I have also tried clearing the cache yet it still show Times New Roman. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late I suppose but the issue was with Google itself. They changed their `Google Fonts` URL from

```
Http
```

to

```
Https
```

Comment: They didn't change it, the HTTP URL responds with some CSS, but it's more likely you were developing/testing your site using HTTPS so your browser(s) would not make requests to insecure resources.

Comment: ahh right... that makes sense!! thanks for clearing :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the correct font-weight is specified in your CSS rule when applying a font to a header.

```
h1 
{
  font-family: Lobster, cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amol.. I have specified font-weight for most of my styles.. but let me make sure on my styles. Thanks again :)

Comment: Didn't work Amol :( - I have now only three styles for Open Sans in the whole website. body { font-family: 'Open Sans', Times New Roman, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; color: #4c4c4c; }           p { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Calibri, Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400;} h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: 'Open Sans', Times New Roman, Arial;
padding-bottom: 6px; color: #474747; line-height: 1em; font-weight: 300; } thanks :)